How to enable top, bottom, left and right on Tailwind config?
I'm using Tailwind with all features disabled by default on core plugins section.
How do I enable the usage of top-0, bottom-0, etc for use?
I've already enabled the inset option but it keeps not working, should I enable another option?
Tailwind version: 3.4.1

inset is the correct option, see this Tailwind Play. It would seem like there could be some other misconfiguration that you forgot to provide.
